# How to share the object in JSContext with other JSContext

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, uiwebview, javascriptcore

The comment in `JSContextRef.h` for `JSContextGroupCreate` says:

> A JSContextGroup associates JavaScript contexts with one another.
>    Contexts in the same group may share and exchange JavaScript objects. Sharing and/or exchanging
>    JavaScript objects between contexts in different groups will produce undefined behavior.

That means a JSContextGroup can have different JSContexts, and they can share the objects in different JSContexts.

Is that means `ctx2` can access `some_object` via `ctx2[@"some_object"]` if `ctx1[@"some_object"]=@(1)` and `ctx1` is in the same `JSContentGroup` of `ctx2`?

What I want to do is executing different JavaScripts in different `JSContent`s separately and I can delete one of the `JSContent` to disable the specific JavaScript.